# Python: regex findall

Tags: python, regex

Iam using python regex to extract certain values from a given string. This is my string:

mystring.txt

```
sometext
somemore    text here

some  other text

              course: course1
Id              Name                marks
____________________________________________________
1               student1            65
2               student2            75
3               MyName              69
4               student4            43

              course: course2
Id              Name                marks
____________________________________________________
1               student1            84
2               student2            73
8               student7            99
4               student4            32

              course: course4
Id              Name                marks
____________________________________________________
1               student1            97
3               MyName              60
8               student6            82
```

and I need to extract the course name and corresponding marks for a particular student. For example, I need the course and marks for `MyName` from the above string.

I tried:

```
re.findall(".*?course: (\w+).*?MyName\s+(\d+).*?",buff,re.DOTALL)
```

But this works only if MyName is present under each course, but not if MyName is missing in some of the course, like in my example string.

Here I get output as: `[('course1', '69'), ('course2', '60')]`

but what actually what I want to achive is: `[('course1', '69'), ('course4', '60')]`

what would be the correct regex for this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python    
import re

buffer_fp = open("mystring.txt","r+")
buff = buffer_fp.read()
buffer_fp.close()
print re.findall(".*?course: (\w+).*?MyName\s+(\d+).*?",buff,re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.*?course: (\w+)(?:(?!\bcourse\b).)*MyName\s+(\d+).*?

                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can try this.See demo.Just use a lookahead based quantifier which will search for `MyName` before a `course` just before it.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/26

Comment: what are the g,s and flags? I understand s is equivalant to re.DOTALL. I thought g is for findall, but then using this regex in python code is giving a different output

Comment: But re.findall(".*?course: (\w+)(?:(?!\bcourse\b).)*MyName\s+(\d+).*?",buff,re.DOTALL) outputs : [('course1', '60')] :(

Comment: @Deepa `print re.findall(r".*?course: (\w+)(?:(?!\bcourse\b).)*MyName\s+(\d+).*?",x,flags=re.DOTALL)` i have tried this code and its working for me

Comment: oops.. sorry I have been trying without the  r prefix. Dont get what difference that makes. :) r prefix is for not translating escapes right?wonder why did that affect the op

Comment: @Deepa python interprets \b as its.own.bell.or.so...but we want it.to.be.word.boundary....so.we have to.use r

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is impossible to do in a single regular expression. They are not all-powerful.

Even if you find a way, *don't do this*. Your non-working regex is already close to unreadable; a working solution is likely to be even more so. You can most likely do this in just a few lines of meaningful code. Pseudocode solution:

```
for line in buff:
    if it is a course line:
        set the course variable
    if it is a MyName line:
        add (course, marks) to the list of matches
```

Note that this could (and probably should) involve regexes in each of those if blocks. It's not a case of choosing between the hammer and the screwdriver to the exclusion of the other, but rather using them both for what they do best.

Comment: Guess you underestimated regex :)

Comment: @vks I guess I did. But respectfully, your solution proves my point. That regex is illegible garbage - good luck to the OP if their requirements ever change and they need to try to fix it. It reads more like Perl than Python.

Comment: it's illegible garbage for the one who can't understand :)